# how to replace send url before send data to facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook

how to replace send url before send data to facebook?

I need to replace url when click the facebook btn . how to do it?

```
<fb:like href="%my_url" layout="standard" action="like" show_faces="true" share="true"></fb:like>
<fb:share-button href="%my_url" type="button_count"></fb:share-button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* ------- 
        when click facebook button , before send data to facebook,
        i need to replace the "%my_url" string to my pointed url , then send to facebook
        any facebook function to do this job?
     ------- */
    FB.???(
        this.url = replace('%my_url','http://www.google.com');
    )

</script>
```

Comment: Why you need to this O.o, this some kind of `XSS attack` against the user's wants!

Comment: Yeah, what are you trying to do here? It looks like you want to display a like button for one URL but change the URL it is for when someone clicks on it - sounds dishonest to me.